# Help proving operator inequality

Tags: operator-theory, operator-algebras, trace

Given $P \geq 0$, I need to show that $2Tr(P^{5/2}) \leq Tr(P^3) + Tr(P^2)$. It's trivial to show that the RHS is the trace of a positive operator, but I'm at a loss on how to actually prove this inequality...

Comment: You could use the fact that $2x^{\frac{5}{2}} \le x^2+x^3$ for all $x \ge 0$, choose an orthonormal basis of eigenvectors for $P$, and use the inequality applied to the eigenvalues. But Mateusz's solution is far more elegant...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have $P^3 + P^2 - 2 P^{\frac{5}{2}} = (P^{\frac{3}{2}} - P)^{2} \geq 0$, so the trace is also non-negative, and this is the announced inequality.

Comment: How do we know that $P^{\frac{3}{2}} \geq P$?

Comment: It isn't necessarily so, but it doesn't matter because $A^2 \geq 0$ for every self-adjoint $A$, essentially because in that case $A^2 = A^{\ast}A$.

Comment: Ah, of course. Thank you!